# XML/HTML Deminify Program

Tags: java, regex, minify

I am writing a Java program which will deminify any HTML/XML file from a single line to multiple lines (structured way). The method is simple. I am using a regex to split the single string into multiple strings and append a new line (\n) to each of those substring. BUT the program is not able to split my single string at all. Could any1 help me with this? Below is my program:

```
package Deminifier;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Deminifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deminifier demo = new Deminifier ();
        demo.execute();
    }

    public void execute(){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String currentLine;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));


        while((currentLine = br.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println("Input text is as follows:");
            System.out.println(currentLine);
            Deminifier demo = new Deminifier();
            System.out.println("Output Formatted text is as follows:");
            demo.toDeminify(currentLine);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void toDeminify(String currentLine) {
        String lineToParse = currentLine;
        String returnString =null;
        String[] splitString = (lineToParse.split("</([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)\b[^>]*>"));
        System.out.println("Number of lines:"+splitString.length);
        for (String s : splitString) {
            System.out.println(s+"\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this matter? why is my String array "split String" returning just "1" array element? I have tried the regex expression and it works in one of my application (is able to identify all end tags).

Comment: Your regex looks a bit suspect. Can you give an example of the closing tag that you're hoping to match with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you're doing a split on the ending tag, which means that it will not be present in any of the items in the returned array.  You probably want to use something like `replaceAll`.  Your regex also looks a bit suspect, but it's hard to tell without being able to see an example input file.

You can adapt the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("</[^>]+>");
while((currentLine = br.readLine())!= null){
    System.out.println("Input text is as follows:");
    System.out.println(currentLine);
    System.out.println("Output Formatted text is as follows:");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(currentLine);
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$0\n"));
}
```

Also, in your original code you are instantiating `Deminifier` inside of the loop, you'd want to move that outside.

Comment: Thanks... I havent used regex or pattern class ever.. so this was new to me!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a file encoding issue? If the file is using UTF-8 but FileReader is expecting US-ASCII then you will probably experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression seems to assume that the HTML is all uppercase. Is that really the case?

Otherwise, try

```
</([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\b[^>]*>
```

which may also be written shorter as

```
</[a-zA-Z]\w*?>
```

(I think, haven't tested it)